# the remote name could not be resolved 'www.nuget.org'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

Just recently I am having trouble accessing the nuget.org website and using the Package manager inside of Visual Studio 2012. In fact just yesterday evening when I attempted to install some packages I encountered the above error. In addition I can not access www.nuget.org from any of my web browsers or my iPad on the same network.

As far as I am aware no changes have taken place on my network. I attempted to navigate to www.nuget.org through a proxy and it did load. So I can only assume there is a problem with my network/IP.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is probably the DNS provider, to test try to extract the ip address of `www.nuget.org` (I did that for you, it is `http://65.52.233.252/`), try to connect from your browser with the ip address without proxy, if it works the your dns provider has an issue,

you can have a quick solution and use [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) by entring there ip address in you dns configuration,

Comment: Hey, thank you, yeah this seems to be the problem. The IP does work so will use this and OpenDNS for the mean time.